# convert date string sored in mysql from dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to DD MMM YYYY

Tags: php, mysql, string, date

i have a date in my mysql database that i would like to read into a variable/array and then convert from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss to DD MMM YYYY. Is this possible and if so, how would i go about doing so.

Comment: what column type is used in mysql? datetime? varchar?

Answer (score 3):

For any kind of date format conversion, first you convert the old date to a timestamp, then format the timestamp into a date.

Example:

```
$old = "6-2-1992 10:24 PM";
$new = date("d/M/Y",strtotime($old));
echo $new; // result: 06/Feb/1992
```

Just be very careful that you don't run afoul of the US format vs. UK format (ie. is 3/4 the 3rd of April or the 4th of March?)

Comment: [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or [`strptime`](http://us.php.net/strptime) could be used to explicitly specify the expected format.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a datetime field (as it appears), just let MySQL give you the date as a timestamp:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_date) As my_timestamp
```

Then you can use [php](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) to format the timestamp as you like:

```
$formatted_date = date("d m Y",$timestamp);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store it in a variable and do the conversion using PHP?  If it's a datetime field just use the DATE_FORMAT function in the query to convert it right off the bat.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d/%b/%Y') datetime FROM table
```